# Learning Python BeautifulSoup, Why do I have to use two elements in a For loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, object, beautifulsoup, new-operator

I'm practicing some web scraping with BS, I've manage to extract the info I want with a For loop, and enumerate, but for some reason I have to use two elements in For loop because if not it doesn't work.

Let me exaplain with detail, First Im selecting the tags that have the info I want and storing them into a BS object, in this case the tag is:

```
 <code>"Some text im interested in"</code>
```

So I selected it like this

```
tags = soup.select("code")
```

but "tags" is a BS object is not pretty and have the whole string with the tag in it, so then I use the getText() method on it like this:

```
tags[1].getText()
```

This allows me to extract the string of the first entry of the tags BS object.
For me to be able to extract the whole information in the way i want, I implement a For Loop enumerating and iterating over the BS object and appending the result in a list, let me show you my function:

```
def my_function(bs_object):
   new_list = []
   for i in enumerate(bs_object):
       data_entry = bs_object[i].getText()
       new_list.append(data_entry)
   return new_list
```

But for some reason the above function doesn't work, doing research I found that it works if I do this:

```
def my_function(bs_object):
   new_list = []
   for i, item in enumerate(bs_object):
       data_entry = bs_object[i].getText()
       new_list.append(data_entry)
   return new_list
```

I want to understand why is this? what does the "item" second element does in the For loop?
Or maybe I'm not doing the **scraping** in the best way? should I use another method?

Comment: The enumerate function is designed to return two values: An index, and the value at that index position in the list.    Since you don't need the value for your loop, instead of enumerate, you can use `for i in range(len(bs_object))`

Comment: Actually, you don't need the index at all. you could simply use: `for item in bs_object: data_entry = item.getText()`, which is more Pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

With the enumerate function you iterate not only the object itself, BUT you also get the index!

```
colors = ["green", "blue", "red"]
```

**without enumerate**:

```
for c in colors:
    print(c)
```

output:

```
green
blue
red
```

but **with enumerate** you can now also get the index!
This is sometimes useful to have.

```
for i, c in enumerate(colors):
    print(c) 
    print(i)
```

output:

```
green
0
blue
1
red
2
```

So if you do not need the index, you don't need to use enumerate.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed exaplantion! I understand now, since i used the enumerate method I needed both elemetns, but as @RufusVS mentions, for what I want I don't have to use enumerate at all, thanks to both!